# Use laravel on azure webapp

Tags: php, laravel, azure, laravel-artisan

My project is developed with larval, then i am trying to use azure for web server.

I am copying folder laravel in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel5`. Next I run php artisan serve.

Then I test on `http://localhost:8000/index` (test on remote websever). It's ok.

But if I access my url for example `http://bobdict.cloudapp.net/index`, it say page not found.

What is the problem?

I am a newbie for this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using IIS to host your PHP application on Azure VM.

As the entrance of laravel application locates in `public` folder in the root directory of the application. You can test to browse `http://bobdict.cloudapp.net/public/index` to test whether you have deploy laravel application successfully. Then to config URL rewrite for friendly URL pattern. You can create the `web.config` manually in your root directory of your application.
You can refer to http://blog.qbotx.com/basic-laravel-5-on-microsoft-azure-part-1/ for the content of `web.config`.

Comment: yes it ok now after i put web.config and change physical path
thank you

Answer (score 0):

in azure portal configure docroot to
                       wwwroot/laravel5/public

Comment: where is azure portal configure can't find

Comment: sry im on my phone , you can google it(how to change doc root on azure)

Comment: i can't find web.config and web.cloud.config

Comment: can't find config in my vm

Comment: am use vm not cloud service

Comment: in the portal after u login, go to ur app dashboard(forgot how exactly) and check all the pannels(at the bottom u will find it) change root folder/ or document root

Comment: not available clound service that contain virtual machine

Comment: ah i didnt know about that